# Do I have to check the fingerprint of new received OpenPGP public key, if it has been sent in a signed and encrypted email from a verified source?

Tags: encryption, email

It is well know that beginning an email relation with PGP (aka GnuPG or OpenPGP) encryption, both sides A and B have to exchange their public keys. The very first step can't be done by encrypted mail, since the necessary public key is not known to the other side. But it can be done with a signed mail, since the sender has his own private key, which is necessary to compute the signature.

If a man in the middle (MIM) interferes in that phase and would continue to interfere in subsequent mail exchanges between A and B, MIM might exchange the public key of A by a faked public(A,MIM) for which MIM retains the private key private(A,MIM). MIM could also sign the message with private(A,MIM). The faked but "correctly" signed and unencrypted mail would look perfectly ok when received at B.

Now B has received something which looks for him as a public key of A, so he might even continue the exchange of keys with signed and encrypted email. But that would not make it better:

If B returns his public(B) to A, MIM might replace it with his self generated public(B,MIM) and sign it with his retained private(B,MIM). He would encode it with public(A), so A would receive an encrypted and signed mail with an attached public key which is not the real public key of B. But A could decode the message and the contained key and since everything looks good, he might use it. But then  MIM can insert himself into every subsequent email exchange between A and B, and can even change exchanged signed and encrypted messages as desired.

To prevent such scenarios, **users of OpenPGP are advised to check the fingerprints of exchanged public keys and use other means than email in oder to not fall into such a trap** of a possible MIM. If both sides mutually check the other side's fingerprints of their respective public keys, they would detect MIM's intervention.

My question is:

Once an OpenPGP exchange **has been verified by comparing the fingerprints** (i.e. no MIM attack has happened and MIM is not able to continue a substitution attack as above), **will it still be necessary to check the fingerprint of another new public key**, if for instance A generates a new public key public'(A) **and sends it in a signed and encrypted mail to B using the initially verified public(B)? Does B have to verify the received key public'(A) again by means independent from email?**

What would be an intervention scenario from a MIM in such a set up? My reasoning is:

1. MIM would have to decrypt the message from A to B first which he can't because it is encrypted with B's public key for which MIM does not have the private counterpart.
   However MIM would be able to attach another public key for which he retains his own private key, like in the scenario above.

   MIM would even be able to sign the message with his faked key, so B would receive an encrypted an signed message which looks good. However the rest of the original message would most probably be utterly wrong or MIM would have to suppress it or supply something else, since MIM could not decrypt the real message.
2. If B would accept the wrong public key without checking the fingerprint, he might answer to A with encrypted and signed messages, which MIM can read and substitute with something else. But he can't encrypt the message properly for A, since he does not have  public'(A). The conclusion would be to accept only encrypted **and** signed emails (this is not clear to many, though).
3. One might argue that MIM might have received public'(A) by other means. In this case, he might be able to encode a manipulated mail from B to A. But he would not be able to sign it, lacking private(B), since he does not have a substituted private(B,MIM) which A trusts, as in the scenario above.

**Is anything wrong with this reasoning?**

**Could the rule "always check the fingerprint before you trust a public key" be relaxed to "... except if a new key is received by a signed and encrypted message if the previous key of the counterpart has been verified before".**

Comment: This should really be asked in [security.se].

Comment: muru, I have posted a link to this question in the recommended forum. I got a comment "Please clarify...". I have thoroughly reviewed and checked my question and added improvements.The parallel question now runs at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/261573/do-i-have-to-check-the-fingerprint-of-new-received-openpgp-public-key-if-it-has. If answers are received there, I will mirror them here after answering my question and vice versa. During the answering period one should have both places in the view.